# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in my simple program about python module

Tags: python, typeerror, python-import, python-module

This is my Python module:

```
main.py
fib/
    __init__.py
    fib.py
    hello.py
```

`fib.py` defined function `fib()`, `hello.py` define function `hello()`.

`main.py` is

```
from fib import *
hello()
```

`__init__.py` is

```
__all__ = ["fib", "hello"]
```

I write this code just for practice.Not for work

I run `main.py` it print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tes.py", line 5, in <module>
    hello()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why? I had list hello in `__all__`

Comment: Repeat after me: Python is not Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've imported the `hello` module with the `from fib import *` line, but you are not referencing the `hello` function in that module.

Do this instead:

```
from fib import *
hello.hello()
```

or this:

```
from fib.hello import *
hello()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are importing the module, not the method.  You probably need to be doing `hello.hello()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you import module but not function in it, you can try:

```
hello.hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `hello()` after using only `from fib import *`, you should replace your `__init__.py` file with:

```
from hello import hello
from fib import fib

__all__ = ['fib', 'hello']
```

This imports the `fib` and `hello` functions into the top-level `fib` module.  This way, when you call `from fib import *`, the **function** `hello()` will be in your namespace, not the **module** `hello` as you currently have it implemented.